# Not getting http request custom header

Tags: php, angularjs, redhat

I am setting http headers in angular js interceptor to make a http request but on php end not getting header.

```
   var key = sessionStorage.getItem('user_type');
            //for app version
            config.headers['AppVersion'] = '1.0';
            config.headers['language'] = web_language;
            if(key == null)
            {
                if(localStorage.getItem('user_type'))
                {
                    config.headers['user_type'] = localStorage.getItem('user_type');
                }
                else
                {
                    config.headers['user_type'] = '';   
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                config.headers['user_type'] = key;
            }
            return config;
```

In browser in network tab in headers i can see the user_type value sent in request.

In php I am using codeigniter:-

```
$user_type = $this->input->get_request_header('user_type');
```

I want to fetch user_type header in php end but not getting.
I am using the linux redhat server godaddy hosting.

Comment: What does `console.log('key is ' + key);` and ` if(key == null) { console.log(' LS value is ' + localStorage.getItem('user_type')); }` print? What I'm trying to find out here is whether the values of `key` and the one in the localstorage under the key `user_type` is what you expect it to be or not.

Comment: Why did you not include the PHP code? What makes you think the problem is in the AngularJS code?

Comment: @georgeawg you are right, now I added php code,it seems that angular js code in working correctly..